# Multithreading puzzle, why is there a race condition?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, locking, race-condition

Considering the following code, I have been unable to figure out why am I seeing a race condition. I am fully aware that the code is bad in all aspects, so no need to comment on that. *The main question is why this code is causing an exception due to a race condition.*

Consider the following (unnecessary as there is C# `Monitor`) implementation of a lock-like class:

```
public class DoActionLock
{
    private readonly object _lock = new object();
    private bool _isLocked;

    public void DoAfterAcquiringLock(Action action)
    {
        // wait till we have the lock
        while (TryAcquireLock())
            Thread.Sleep(20);

        try
        {
            action.Invoke();
        }
        finally
        {
            ReleaseLock();
        }
    }

    public bool TryAcquireLock()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (_isLocked)
                return false;
            _isLocked = true;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void ReleaseLock()
    {
        lock (_lock)
            _isLocked = false;
    }
}
```

And now consider the following test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void DoActionLock_GetLockAndDoActionLock_ShouldNotAllow()
{
    var reentrylock = new DoActionLock();
    var someobj = new object();

    var task = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (reentrylock.TryAcquireLock())
            {
                someobj = new object();
                someobj.ToString();
                reentrylock.ReleaseLock();
            }
        }
    });

    var task1 = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            reentrylock.DoAfterAcquiringLock(() => someobj = null);
        }
    });
    task.Wait();
    task1.Wait();
}
```

If you run this test, there always is a null pointer exception in `someobj.ToString();`. Meaning that `task1` is setting `someobj` to null while `task` is running within the lock. Thus clearly showing that the lock is not working properly. But even knowing that I haven't been able to figure out why this happens. I would appreciate any help, this is breaking my brain.

Comment: Maybe you intended `while (!TryAcquireLock())` instead of `while (TryAcquireLock())`?

Comment: I see only the problem written by Theodor... The `lock` is a full barrier, so the `_islocked` inside will be really read/written (by "really" I mean that the compiler can't cache the value, can't pre-read, can't post-write and so on. The access to the memory of the variable WILL be made inside the lock and WILL read the current value/WILL write the new value)

Comment: this is so stupid i can't believe i didn't see it before... thanks @TheodorZoulias you are totally right. It was getting in the action with the _islocked false... I am going to leave this question here just to remember how easy is to miss stuff sometimes.